# Invalid output while converting string to its numeric value

Tags: java, recursion

```
public class StringConverter
{
    public static int convert(String numString){
    if(numString.isEmpty()){
        return 0;
    }
    int result = convert(numString.substring(1));

    int val = numString.charAt(0) - '0';
    result += Math.pow(10,numString.length()-1)*val;

    return result;
  }
}
```

Its working fine, but im having trouble understanding why im getting this kind of output

> Value of "1234" is 1234
>
> Value of "921" is 921
>
> Value of "0" is 0
>
> Value of "0034" is 34
>
> Value of "-4" is -26
>
> Value of "-400001" is -2599999
>
> Value of "ABC" is 1899

When I'm supposed to get

> Value of "1234" is 1234
>
> Value of "921" is 921
>
> Value of "0" is 0
>
> Value of "0034" is 34
>
> Value of "-4" is -4
>
> Value of "-400001" is -400001
>
> Value of "ABC" is 0

Comment: You'll probably need to add some special logic to handle negative numbers.  You haven't written any, so it seems unreasonable to expect negatives to just work correctly.

Comment: if char is non numeric return 0?

Comment: Integer.valueOf(number) . This will handle negative numbers as well and throw exception for any non numeric entry that you will need to handle.

Answer (score -1):

Easiest way is to use try and catch. If it try to parse an alphabetical string then  NumberFormatException is thrown.

```
public static int convert(String numString){
    try{
        return Integer.valueOf(numString);
    }catch (NumberFormatException e){
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this instead:

```
public static int convert(String value){

    try{
    return value == null || value.trim().isEmpty() || value.equals("null") ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(value);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        return 0;
    }
  }
```